# How to create a factory containing controllers that contain the factory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, factory

I'm trying to create a factory which will hold the a list of "child" controllers in a dictionary. These child controllers must contain the factory so that they can access other child controllers. Here is the factory:

```
public interface IChildControllerFactory
{
    IChildController GetChildController(object item);
}


public class ChildControllerFactory : IChildControllerFactory
{
    private Dictionary<string, IChildController> _childControllerDictionary;

    public ChildControllerFactory(IEnumerable<IChildController> childControllers)
    {
        var childControllerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, IChildController>();

        //code to build dictionary
        _childControllerDictionary = childControllerDictionary;
    }

    public IChildController GetChildController(object item)
    {
        return _childControllerDictionary.Where(x => x.Key == item.GetType().Name).Select(x => x.Value).First();
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a child controller:

```
public class ChildController : Controller, IChildController<TViewModel, TModel>
{
    private IChildControllerFactory _childControllerFactory;

    public ChildController(IChildControllerFactory childControllerFactory) //this will cause a circular reference
    {
        _childControllerFactory = childControllerFactory;
    }

    public ActionResult GetChildViewModel(object child)
    {
        var model = _childControllerFactory.GetChildController(child).ToViewModel(survey);
        return PartialView("Child.ascx", model);
    }
}
```

And the inherited interface:

```
public interface IChildController<TViewModel, TModel>
{
    int Create(object item);
    object Save(object item);
    object ToViewModel(object item);
}
```

The child controllers are all registered, and the factory is specified as a Singleton with Structure Map.

Because the child controller need the Factory, setting the factory in the constructor using dependency injection will cause a circular reference because the first time the Factory is initialized, it will initialize all child controllers, and each child controller will try to initialize the Factory (which is already executing).

How can I get the factory to instantiate all the child controllers and then have it accessible from those child controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about this. A `childController` can only work if it has assigned a Factory right? So before a `childFactory` is created, a childControll is de facto useless. That said I would do something like:

```
public class ChildController : Controller, IChildController<TViewModel, TModel>
{
    private IChildControllerFactory _childControllerFactory;

    public ChildController() 
    {
    }

    public void setChildControllerFactory( IChildControllerFactory childControllerFactory )
    {
       _childControllerFactory = childControllerFactory;
    }

    public ActionResult GetChildViewModel(object child)
    {
        var model = _childControllerFactory.GetChildController(child).ToViewModel(survey);
        return PartialView("Child.ascx", model);
    }
}
```

so your `ChildControllerFactory` would be something like:

```
public ChildControllerFactory(IEnumerable<IChildController> childControllers)
{
    var childControllerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, IChildController>();
    _childControllerDictionary = childControllerDictionary;
    for(IChildController i in _childControllerDictionary) i.setChildControllerFactory(this);
}
```

I did not test it but I don't see the necessity of the concrete object to have the factory passed in the constructor since you're storing the Dictionary of this objects in your factory.

Comment: This does seem to solve most of the problems that I had, but how is _childControllerFactory set when there's a request from the page? We know we can't use dependency injection in the constructor, but I suppose I could override the Initialize controller method to get and set the instance of the factory. Would this be recommended?

Comment: Are you referring to this? http://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2012/06/04/mvc-controller-factory/